# Search specific characters within a field in a table in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a number of fields that have unordered information and Ineed to find certain records that have certain pattern search. For example:

```
field1 , field2
1      , "house, cars, people"
2      , "mazda, Jefff, cat 15th stre"
3      , "do, money, arreaz, cars"
.
.
N      , "cars, postgres, json, abat"
```

As I postgres to search only the records that have the word "cars"

Thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use regular expressions to match your particular example you can do the following:

```
field2  ~ '^cars$'  or
field2  ~ ',cars,'  or
field2  ~ '^cars,'  or
field2  ~ ',cars$'
```

With regular expressions you can search commas at the beginning of a string, at the end of a string, the beginning of a string, etc..

Answer (score 0):

If PostgreSQL's [regular expressions' definition of word characters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) (words consit of alphanumeric character(s) and/or the underscore `_`) is good enough for you, you can use this:

```
WHERE field2  ~ '\mcars\M'
```

You can also use the [`pg_trgm` contrib module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html), to speed up your queries.

But I strongly recommend, you should check [PostgreSQL's full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) support (if you want search in your field like in a description), or you should revise your structure (f.ex. you could use another table for `field2` entries (preferred), or even an array instead of the plain comma-separated field).